# How to select all text boxes with a specific tag

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq

Using c# 6 windows forms, I want to choose all textBoxes with the tag "txt".
I have confirm that there are several of them with the tag "txt". Then, I want to clear the text. But the following code is not choosing any.

```
this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
             .Where(textBox => textBox.Tag.ToString() == "txt").ToList()
             .ForEach(textBox => textBox.Clear());
```

Comment: Maybe they are not direct child of `Form` and you placed them in a some other container controls. - Also be aware of probable `NullReferenceException` here `textBox.Tag.ToString()`.

Comment: what type of control is `this`?

Comment: I have this code for the ones in GroupBoxes -> foreach (var textBox in Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().Where(textBox => textBox.Tag?.ToString() == "txt").SelectMany(groupBox => groupBox.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()))
            {
                
                textBox.Clear();
            }

Comment: they are textboxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code almost work, use this:

```
        this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
            .Where(text =>!(text.Tag == null) && text.Tag.ToString() == "txt").ToList()
            .ForEach(text => text.Clear());
```